# Start Linux with a certain scheduler?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to start the Linux operating system with a certain number of cores / a certain scheduler?

Comment: You might want to check out [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-enable-disable-cpus-limiting-cpu-count-in-centos-rhel/) and [here](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/how-to-change-io-scheduler-permanently-linux/) for starting points.

Comment: Thank you, I did google but did not find these results. Thanks. What did you google?

Comment: I searched for `linux scheduler sysconf` and `linux activate cores`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/block/switching-sched.html

also, `man sysctl`

xsadfasdfasdgfasgfasgasdfg - to make the minimal post thingy shut up